# Creating a good armature for a rig/skeleton/bones

Tags: python, armature

I am creating a rig/skeleton/bones in Blender python, using bpy, here: https://github.com/coderextreme/X3DJSONLD/blob/master/blend/blenderskeleton.py

I was looking at the code and in Blender and I realized that `skeleton = bpy.data.objects.new("Armature", bpy.data.armatures.new("Armature"))` looked a little misguided.  Does someone have a better suggestion how to add an armature?

Comment: I see that after running your line, an armature appears in the outliner, but not the scene. Try "bpy.ops.object.armature_add()" and then follow it with "skeleton = bpy.context.object" If the default armature isn't what you need, you may want to explore the python console and type into it"bpy.ops.object.armature_" and then press "Tab" to see the other options (basic human metarig, bird metarig, etc...)

Comment: I am using the standard HAnimJoints to define my “bones.”  I’ve changed the code a bit if you want to review it.